# remove / replace unwanted prefixed info from `class` name

Tags: jquery, css, regex

I am getting `style` from backend. it has unwanted prefix with it. i would replace the same without the prefix. what would be the correct way?

here is what what i am getting:

```
<style>
043BF83A8FB24A418DA4248840101DE5 .cls_0 {
font:26px 'Arial';
color:rgb(0,0,0);
font-weight:bold;
}

043BF83A8FB24A418DA4248840101DE5 .cls_1 {
font:26px 'Arial';
color:rgb(0,0,0);
}

043BF83A8FB24A418DA4248840101DE5 .cls_11 {
font:13px 'Arial';
color:rgb(0,0,0);
}

043BF83A8FB24A418DA4248840101DE5 .cls_12 {
font:16px 'Arial';
color:rgb(0,0,0);
font-weight:bold;
}

043BF83A8FB24A418DA4248840101DE5 .cls_13 {
font:16px 'Arial';
color:rgb(0,0,0);
}
</style>
```

here is what i am required..

```
<style>
.cls_0 {
font:26px 'Arial';
color:rgb(0,0,0);
font-weight:bold;
}

 .cls_1 {
font:26px 'Arial';
color:rgb(0,0,0);
}

.cls_11 {
font:13px 'Arial';
color:rgb(0,0,0);
}

.cls_12 {
font:16px 'Arial';
color:rgb(0,0,0);
font-weight:bold;
}

.cls_13 {
font:16px 'Arial';
color:rgb(0,0,0);
}
</style>
```

my try, but fails:

```
var styleText = $('style').get(1).html();
console.log(styleText); //throw error as  "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution :

```
$('style').html(function(_,h){
  return h.replace(/^\w+ (\.\w+)/gm,'$1');
});
```

This removes any string at the start of a line and before a class selector in any `<style>` element.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/vihedocite/1/edit)

Comment: I guess, you are counting the letter for `32`. but when the id gets less than the digit will be the proplem again. can't we text the `.word {' and remove prefixed text?

Comment: You mean you want to handle shorter textes ? Then use `/^\w+/gm`

Comment: But it removes even property name too.. ('font-size' :12px) became (":12px), can you confirm this? `return h.replace(/^\d\w+/gm,'');`

Comment: OK. See updated answer then. It removes the id only if it's at the start of the line and before a class.

Comment: In stored variable this is not working. my case is replacing the `html` stored in variable. http://jsfiddle.net/msnyyphm/2/

Comment: @3gwebtrain [I fixed your code](http://jsfiddle.net/q3hseab3/). But this is a very different question now and it looks like you're on the wrong path overall.

Comment: @3gwebtrain Your code looks random so it's hard to know what you even try to achieve. Is it [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1qk1n3da/) ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the prefix is hexadecimal, so this will do the job:

```
str.replace(/^[A-F0-9]+\s+/gm, '')
```